# VFP - Why SELECT SQL is returning date as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, visual-foxpro, type-mismatch

I have a table to do some test in performance, etc. In this table I have a field "cpDATA" as DATE type, and another field "cpDATATIME" as datetime type.

Does anybody know why when I use "SELECT * FROM teste" this return "cpDATA" as string?

This is the script for the table:

---

```
CREATE TABLE teste](
    [CpTexto] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CpData] [date] NULL,
    [CpDataTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [CpValor] [numeric](15, 5) NULL,
    [CpInteiro] [int] NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

And this is for SQLEXECUTE:

```
lcNumConex = 1
pStringSQL = [SELECT * FROM TESTE]
pCursor = [tmpResult]

SQLEXEC(lcNumConex,pStringSql,pCursor)
```

---

When I use this, I can see on the cursor created as result from query, the field "cpDATA" as string instead of date type.

Does anybody help me?

Comment: How are you observing the result?

Comment: Try this please: [SELECT [CpTexto],CTOD([CpData]),[CpDataTime],[CpValor],[CpInteiro],
   [ID] FROM TESTE]

Comment: Joel ... I do execute this "select script" by "SQLEXECUT" and it has a cursor as a result. If I browse this cursor or if I look at this cursor structure, its using the char type on this field.

Answer (score 2):

Some older database providers do not support the newer `date` data type in SQL Server. It is possible, perhaps even likely, that you're getting a text representation due to the provider's inability to represent that data type with an underlying numeric value, since it doesn't know what the data type is.

You could possibly work around this by doing `SELECT cpData = Convert(datetime, cpData) FROM ...` to provide an older data type that is almost certainly supported. However, I'm not sure how updates back against the table would work.

Even better, check and see if there is an updated provider (the driver for your database connection) such as "SQL Server Native Client", which may support the new data types.

Comment: ErikE ... thanks for your answer. When you wrote "providers" I tried to change the driver for my connection.

By default, the application was taking the "SQL SERVER" driver. When I changed it to use "{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}" it works fine.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the info! I updated my answer to suggest checking providers. If it was useful to you, would you consider marking my answer as the selected one (click the check mark to the left of it)?